# difference between elimination reactions and oxidation reactions

Tags: elimination, organic-oxidation, c-x-addition

I know that oxidation reactions involve the loss of hydrogen. But is the mechanism the same

Comment: That rather depends on what oxidation or reduction conditions you are considering

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Whether the oxidation of an alochol or the reduction of a carbonyl group follows a certain mechanism depends on the reagents/conditions.

For example:
The sodium borohydride reduction of a ketone follows a nucleophilic addition mechanism:

$$\ce{R2C=O ->[1)\ \ce{NaBH4},\ \ce{CH3OH}][2)\ \ce{H3O+}] R2CHOH}$$
[image]

However, some metal catalyzed hydrogenation reactions are considered to be (nearly) concerted additions. For example, here is the transition state of the key step of the mechanism of the Noyori reduction.

$$\ce{R2C=O ->[\ce{H2}][\ce{RuCl2en2/BINAP}] R2CHOH}$$
[image]

Many oxidations of alcohols follow something of an elimination mechanism. For example, the key step of the Swern oxidation looks like an elimination. 
$$\ce{R2C=O ->[1)\ \ce{DMSO, (COCl)2}][2) \ce{Et3N}] R2CHOH}$$

[image]

There is a second important mechanism: hydride transfer oxidation. This is the prevailing mechanism biochemically, where the alochol is used as a hydride source to simultaneously reduce another compounds.

$$\ce{R2C=O ->[\ce{NAD+}][\ce{base}] R2CHOH}$$

[image]